# Results table for search bar is not showed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a search bar in my app , but i have a problem because i when the user click the search icon , search bar to appear with the results from the last search . This is happen , but as you can see i can't select the row form table . If i try this this view and keyboard dissapear and when i want to make a new search the table with results doesn't show anymore .

[image]

[image]

Any ideea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used SearchBar and SearchDisplayController ?
If **yes**,
then In your tableview datasource method, you should use condition in tableview datasource method of `NumberOfRowsInSection` and also in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` which is shown below

```
If(tableview == myTableView) {

    // Count for Your TableView
    // Display Results for Tableview . Which will be by default

} else {

    // Count for SearchTableView
    // Show Result for Search TableView
}
```

Also You need to use SearchBarDelegate in your .h File.